# How can I recover files from a part of a disk image?

Tags: data-recovery, dd

I am backing up a dying hard drive using dd. Unfortunately the process is taking very long (95KB/s) and I would like to see if I can get some of my files from the part that is already copied (~26GB). I used scalpel and I managed to recover a small part of files, mostly jpeg images. I am afraid that this program finds files that I have deleted and not the ones that are actually still there.
Are there any alternatives I can use?

I am trying to mount the already recovered part but it fails. Do I need to recover the whole disk before I can mount it?

Comment: Are any of those files have filenames you have deleted?  I am going to guess the reason you can't mount is because there isn't any indication where the file ends currently.  Scalpel is likely more forgiving.

Comment: The files scalpel creates have random names, I am not sure if these files were deleted (they are small album covers from my music) because other people were using my disk

Comment: if you have the first part of the partition, it is likely that it will mount, but your file system will be in a sorry state. try and see if you can mount it. as for dd, I second the recommendation for dd_rescue.

Comment: It is the first part of the partition but it is not able to mount. I don't think there are read errors so I don't see a reason why dd_rescue would be faster. Any ideas if the files scalpel returns are previously deleted? And if there is an alternative for all files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `dd` is very slow, I expect that it tries to read faulty sectors many times. Finally it can even happen that `dd` fails.

I would recommend using [dd_rescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/). It is more intelligent regarding read errros. While it might not fully recover your data, it should still be faster and you're able to mount the image earlier.

When you can mount the image, you can simply access the files as they were before (given you have just read problems, not file system problems) and there is no need for Scalpel any more.

Other links:
[Using dd_rescue safely](http://www.manpagez.com/info/ddrescue/ddrescue-1.17/ddrescue_3.php#Important-advice)

Comment: I use conv=sync,noerror so I guess it will not fail. Do you know if it reports read errors when it finds them?

Comment: Sorry, it's 3 years ago, I can't remember. I started with `dd conv=sync,noerror` as well and then switched to `dd_rescue`.